# Receiving Gigs of data from Mobile Service on UpdateAsync method

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

So update operations are working when I locally deploy my azure mobile service. But after I've published it to Azure my app crashes when trying to update data. For example here's two classes of mine:

```
public class TestSet : EntityData
{
    public TestSet()
    {
        this.TestPointAttempts = new List<TestPointAttempt>();
    }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string TestTeamType { get; set; }
    public int FieldTeamNumber { get; set; }
    public int? DispatchTeamNumber { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int TestSetCount { get; set; }

    public string DiscrepancyTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual DiscrepancyType DiscrepancyType { get; set; }

    public string DiscrepancyTestSetId { get; set; }

    public decimal? BER { get; set; }
    public decimal? SSI { get; set; }
    public decimal? BERLat { get; set; }
    public decimal? BERLong { get; set; }

    public string TileId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tile Tile { get; set; }

    public string ScenarioId { get; set; }
    public virtual Scenario Scenario { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TestPointAttempt> TestPointAttempts { get; set; }

}

public class TestPointAttempt : EntityData
{
    [Required]
    public int TestAttemptNumber { get; set; }

    public bool? TalkIn { get; set; }
    public bool? TalkOut { get; set; }
    public decimal? DAQIn { get; set; }
    public decimal? DAQOut { get; set; }
    public decimal? LatIn { get; set; }
    public decimal? LongIn { get; set; }
    public decimal? LatOut { get; set; }
    public decimal? LongOut { get; set; }

    public string TestSetId { get; set; }
    public virtual TestSet TestSet { get; set; }

}
```

I have 1:n relationships set up. It all looks good and new inserts work fine (both local and azure) but Updates don't work when I publish to azure. When it goes to update a TestPointAttempt the app crashes because of low memory errors. It starts gobbling up mbs rising from ~30mb to 1gb in about 5 seconds!!! I used some memory profiling tools and it occurs during deserialization in json.net. Here's my update code:

```
public async Task SaveTestSet(TestSet ts)
{
    IsPending = true;
    ErrorMessage = null;

    try
    {
        var tpas = ts.TestPointAttempts;
        foreach (var tpa in tpas)
        {
            await testPointAttemptTable.UpdateAsync(tpa);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        Console.WriteLine(ErrorMessage);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsPending = false;
    }
}
```

I then used fiddler to look at the response and fiddler would crash too because the response was too big. So now I found out that the mobile service is responding with GIGs of data...but how? I don't even know where to start looking. I debugged the mobile service and the update seems to go through the TableController just fine but it's returning a lot of data....

Where do I start looking on the Mobile Service to see how/why it's returning so much data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was when JSON would attempt to serialize the virtual collections. Since all of my navigation properties were also being serialized it was attempted to send back a huge portion of the database. The solution is to add a json ignore attribute on the navigation properties like so:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Scenario Scenario { get; set; }
```